# Comparison of floating data in txt column with bash

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, awk

I have thousands of files containg a column of non integers data. 
I would like to build a script that iterates through all the folders, checks if the values in the file are equal/different from 0.000000.

The column of data are like the following one:

```
-0.572650
-0.002281
-0.080300
-0.803684
-0.498033
-0.206755
-0.182819
-0.222126
-0.116538
 0.720913
 0.707343
 1.134845
-0.462461
-0.382780
-0.378505
-0.436588
-0.464654
-0.207534
-0.231861
-0.155786
-0.196779
 0.977137
 1.024751
 1.037147
```

I have tried something like:

```
#!/bin/bash


a=$(awk '{print $1}' tmp.txt)


if (( $(echo "$a == 0.000000" |bc -l) ));
 then
 echo "MULLIKEN MISSING"
elif (( $(echo "$a != 0.000000" |bc -l) )); 
 then
echo "OK"
fi
```

but it is does not work in manner I would like to.

I would like the script to be able to detect if the data in column are all equal to 0.000000 or not.

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you want to check if *any* value is zero, or if *all* values are zero?

Comment: Hi! I want to check if there is a value in the column that is equal to zero.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi this code is quite similar to yours and it should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$(awk '{print $1}' tmp.txt)

for i in ${a[@]}; do
    result=$( echo $i == 0.0 | bc -l)
    if [[ $result == "0" ]];
    then
        echo "OK"
    else
        echo "NOT OK"
    fi
done
```

Note that reading with AWK in this way, then using variable as array is not the safest method.

Comment: Hi! Cool, I see. I gonna try immediately! Thanks a lot! Onlu last question: what does @ mean in the variable definition?

Comment: you'll want to quote all your variables: `"${a[@]}"`, `"$i"` -- so that you don't get surprised by unexpected values in the file.

Comment: This is just horrible. Do the comparison in Awk too, like the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 3):

I would stick just with awk: this will be quite efficient as you only need to spawn one process to handle the whole file, as opposed to calling bc for every number.

```
if awk '$1 == 0 {exit 0} END {exit 1}' file; then
    echo "has a zero"
else
    echo "no zeroes"
fi
```

---

**EDIT:** I have a logic error: the awk END block is executed when the `exit` command is called, so the above will **always** exit `1`. Use this instead:

```
if awk 'BEGIN {rc = 1} $1 == 0 {rc = 0; exit} END {exit rc}' file; then
    echo "has a zero"
else
    echo "no zeroes"
fi
```

or, exit 1 when a zero is found. This simplifies the awk command:

```
if awk '$1 == 0 {exit 1}' file; then
    echo "no zeroes"
else
    echo "has a zero"
fi
```

---

If you want to stick with plain bash, you can read each number from the file, and remove the dot so that you only have an integer (no floating point in bash)

```
zero=false
while read -r value; do
    if (( 10#${value//./} == 0 )); then
        zero=true
        break
    fi
done < file

$zero && echo "has a zero" || echo "no zeroes"
```

The `10#` is to force base-10 interpretation, so that bash does not puke on invalid octal numbers like 080000.

Comment: Thanks a lot Glenn! I like the awk solution! I will also try this one.